# Optimize element wise fuzzy match between two lists

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

I have two lists of companies (> 2k entries in the longer list) in different formats that I need to unify. I know that both formats share a stub about 80% of the time, so I'm using fuzzy match to compare both lists:

```
def get_fuzz_score(str1, str2):

    from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
    partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(str1, str2)
    return partial_ratio


a = ['Express Scripts', 'Catamaran Corp', 'Banmedica SA (96.7892%)', 'WebMD', 'ODC', 'Caremerge LLC (Stake%)']
b = ['Doctor on Demand', 'Catamaran', 'Express Scripts Holding Corp', 'ODC, Inc.', 'WebMD Health Services', 'Banmedica']

for i in b:
    for j in a:
        if get_fuzz_score(i, j) > 80:
            # process
```

I'd appreciate thoughts on how to optimize this task for performance (e.g., not have to use 2 for loops).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you installed both fuzzywuzzy AND python-Levenshtein.
The installation of the second package failed and therefore i got a message:

> warnings.warn('Using slow pure-python SequenceMatcher. Install python-Levenshtein to remove this warning')

You can use [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools#itertools.product) to create the cartesian product:

```py
from itertools import product
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def get_fuzz_score(str1, str2):
    partial_ratio = fuzz.partial_ratio(str1, str2)
    return partial_ratio


a = ['Express Scripts', 'Catamaran Corp', 'Banmedica SA (96.7892%)', 'WebMD', 'ODC', 'Caremerge LLC (Stake%)']
b = ['Doctor on Demand', 'Catamaran', 'Express Scripts Holding Corp', 'ODC, Inc.', 'WebMD Health Services', 'Banmedica']

for first, second in product(a, b):
    if get_fuzz_score(first, second) > 80:
        # process
```

If your function get_fuzz_score doesn't grow you can make it obsolete:

```py
from itertools import product
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz  # 

a = ['Express Scripts', 'Catamaran Corp', 'Banmedica SA (96.7892%)', 'WebMD', 'ODC', 'Caremerge LLC (Stake%)']
b = ['Doctor on Demand', 'Catamaran', 'Express Scripts Holding Corp', 'ODC, Inc.', 'WebMD Health Services', 'Banmedica']

for first, second in product(a, b):
    if fuzz.partial_ratio(first, second) > 80:
        pass  # process
```

Comment: itertools.product might be exactly what I need -- will give it a try and report back

Comment: re: python-Levenshtein warning, i fought with that for a long time and ended up having to switch to a Conda environment to fix

Answer (score 3):

first, I would move the import `from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz` from the function to the start of the file.

Next, it appears that you want to check every element, so you are comparing all2all anyway and I don't see simple workaround that.

If the data are 'nice' than you could do some simple heuristic e.g. on a first letter (from the examples you've posted - but that depends on the data).

Best regards

P.s. I would comment If my score would be high enough.

Comment: Looks like your reputation score is indeed high enough for comments :)

Answer (score 3):

`fuzzywuzzy` provides a `process.extract*` family of functions to help with this, e.g:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process

a = ['Express Scripts', 'Catamaran Corp', 'Banmedica SA (96.7892%)', 'WebMD', 'ODC', 'Caremerge LLC (Stake%)']
b = ['Doctor on Demand', 'Catamaran', 'Express Scripts Holding Corp', 'ODC, Inc.', 'WebMD Health Services', 'Banmedica']

for name in a:
    print(name, process.extract(name, b, limit=3))
```

will print out each name in `a` and the three top matches from `b`.

this is still `O(n**2)` but because this library is open source code you get to see how `extract` is defined and maybe just do the [preprocessing](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy/blob/master/fuzzywuzzy/process.py) once rather than every time which would hopefully speed things up a lot